# How to debug Webdriverio cucumber framework in VScode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cucumber, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

I am trying to debug Cucumber scenarios in Visual Studio code and below is launch.json config. Execution is not stopping at the breakpoint. I am not sure whether the generic feature path I have mentioned is correct. Does my launch.json require changes ? I have updated Outfiles name value pair from a similar stack overflow post.

```
{
            "name": "WebdriverIO Test",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["wdio.conf.js", "--spec", "${file}","${workspaceRoot}/test/features/**/*.feature","--tags",
                "${workspaceRoot}/test/stepdefinition/**/*"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/test/features/**/*.feature"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
```

Below is a screenshot of the folder structure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just use `Javascript Debug Terminal` in VSCode to debug my webdriverio-cucumber tests. It's pretty simple and usually requires no extra step to configure. So far I have found it very handy and useful. You'll find more information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_javascript-debug-terminal). Hope that'll help.